# Определение видимости элемента в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот фрейм: https://jsfiddle.net/ex6b8c1h/

js:

```
$('.newsBar').click(function() {
    $('.newsWindow').slideToggle();
});
$('.weatherBar').click(function() {
    $('.weatherWindow').slideToggle();
});
```

html:

```
<div class="newsBar"></div>
<div class="weatherBar"></div>
<div class="newsWindow"></div>
<div class="weatherWindow"></div>
```

css: newsWindow, weatherWindow - `display:none;`

Нужно применить в скрипт условные выражения `if`, `if else`, `else` для реакции:

Если `newsWindow` выполняет функцию `.slideToggle`, при этом `weatherWindow` имеет `display:block;` или же `.show()`, тогда к `weatherWindow` применяем `.hide();`

и наоборот:

Если `weatherWindow` выполняет функцию `.slideToggle`, при этом `newsWindow` имеет `display:block;` или же `.show()`, тогда к `newsWindow` применяем `.hide();`

Никак не получается реализовать из-за недостатка знаний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы проверить является ли элемент видимым вы можете использовать вот такую конструкцию:

```
$('...').is(':visible');
```

С использованием такого подхода, ваш обработчик события `click` для элемента `newsBar` будет иметь вид:

```
$('.newsBar').click(function() {
    $('.newsWindow').slideToggle();
    if ($('.weatherWindow').is(':visible')) {
        $('.weatherWindow').hide();
    }
});
```

Обработчик для события `click` на элементе `.weatherBar` можно построить по аналогии.

Comment: Спасибо большое за конструкцию с чекигом визибла и ответа в целом!

Answer (score 1):

`display: block` и `none` делайте не аттрибутом `style`, а классом, например:

```
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

И присвойте этот класс к открывающемуся диву. Проверять на активность можно кодом:

```
if(elem.hasClass(".active")) {
  //код когда блок активен
}
else {
  //в противном случае
}
```